# Remove all Carriage Returns from sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Carriage Returns are ruining my concatenation formula I'm using to create unique identifiers and my day.

Trying to insert VBA to remove all Carriage Returns from an activesheet with a bit of code I've pinched and the IF statement is crashing.
When I hover over the yellow debugging line I get the pop up 'MyRange = Error 2015'

Any thoughts on the below? Or any better code going?

Thanks

```
Sub RemoveCarriageReturns()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    For Each MyRange In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If 0 < InStr(MyRange, Chr(10)) Then
            MyRange = Replace(MyRange, Chr(10), "")
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Simply: `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Replace Chr(10), "", xlPart`

Comment: You may also want to replace chr(13) just in case the returns are line feeds instead.

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks Gents!

Comment: FYI, Chr(10) is actually a line feed and 13 is a carriage return, rather than vice versa. If you want both: `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Replace vbCrLf, "", xlPart`